# Keyboard shortcut to go to next post in the next feed?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-reader

There is a shortcut `N` that will jump to another post in the same feed ("subscription") but will not jump to another feed when the current post is the last one.

Then there is a `spacebar` shortcut that will scroll down one page and switch to a next feed if necessary but if a post is very very long, I have to hit the spacebar many times in order to reach the next post.

Is there something like `N` that will also take me to the next feed if necessary?

Comment: If you just read your feeds from 'All items' you wouldn't have this problem ;-)

Comment: I tried the "All items" view for some period of time but didn't like it - it's helpful for me if I can peak in which subscription I currently am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift-J/K will navigate feeds/folder, then Shift-O will start reading that feed/folder.

Comment: Not user-friendly at all but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> for `next`/`previous` posts.

For more info on shortcuts in Google Reader press <kbd>?</kbd> to check them all.

Comment: j / k / n doesn't work for jumping between subscriptions (it only moves to next / previous post in the current subscription)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I use `g-t` to to bring up the tag window, then the first letter of the tag (I read tags at different periodicities).

Also, `g-u` brings up the list of subscriptions, where you can type in the feed name. But I always find this a bit overwhelming. In a pinch `?` brings up all of the shortcuts.